# Introducing a "language-trick" tag?

Tags: feature-request, status-declined, tags, meta-tags

Every now and then, I see a question that essentially asks for the language specific tricks. For example: [Find the maximum value in a list of tuples in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13145368/find-the-maximum-value-in-a-list-of-tuples-in-python)

I think if we can allow tagging questions with something like "{language}-trick" then it would be very helpful in filtering and learning some important tricks of a particular language.

Comment: Pleeeeeease no!

Comment: Whyyyyyyyyyyyy?

Comment: sounds like a meta tag. I don't think anyone is going to watch that tag to provide answers to the questions with that tag.

Comment: That will not be used for answering but rather it would be very useful for learning language tricks.

Comment: If it is not used for answering how will those who provide the tricks find the questions?

Comment: It is a meta-tag, we don't like those.  Programmers always ought to prefer *elegance* over tricks anyway.  Google "the story of mel" to learn more.

Comment: How will askers know they could get their problems solved with a _language trick_. We could fairly have a tag like [tag:magic] supported either.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ no, that is already a synonym of [tag:c++] ...

Comment: @rene there's not the slightest blink of _magic_ in c++, it's all plain science. Complex science, yes, but no way _magic_.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ it is all abracadabra to me

Comment: @rene Well, it's `abracadabra<salamaleikum>` to be precise :3

Comment: Honestly, I think it's more `h.ocus().p.ocus()`.

Comment: How does one become an expert in the 'language-tricks' tag anyway?

Answer (score 10):

> it would be very useful for learning language tricks

How?

Before this tag can be useful to you, you have to learn that "language trick" is a thing, that it's a term of art that means something.

Once you stumble across that concept, you then get to wade into this tag and learn... random stuff. Nothing specific, nothing about particular concepts. Just whatever someone decides is a trick. Also, who makes the determination that a particular question or answer constitutes a "trick"?

Plus, you're taking up precious tag real-estate on the question that may be put to better use.

No, cataloging a series of "language tricks" sounds like something that's best done off-site.

Comment: Not necessarily. 

One can start with the basic tutorial of a language and then directly jump to SO to find language specific tricks that he can use to exploit hidden language features for writing good code. 

I agree that there has to be a strict moderation around what is a trick. Maybe we can have some special tags for feature like this.

Comment: @LokeshAgrawal: That is not a useful way to learn things.

Comment: I personally feel I would have liked such collection. Because often a times I end up knowing about a very useful language specific feature too late in the development cycle of my software. I feel that if I would have known about its existence I would have saved a lot of time in writing too complex logic that no one understands now.

Comment: You may suggest refactoring as soon as I discover some tricks like that, but my point is why not to prevent instead of searching for a cure once code is infected.

Comment: @LokeshAgrawal: Yes, and how many not-useful-to-you language features/idioms would you have had to read through to find it? It's not an *effective* way to learn such things. The more effective way to learn them is to search based on the problem you're having. That will lead you to the SO question involving that problem, and therefore to the language trick that *will* help you in your current task.

Comment: No its getting covered in learning time. I will go through the tricks once (maybe quickly after learning a language) or maybe keeping a watch on newly approved tricks. After this exercise, tricks will be sitting somewhere in my unconscious memory. I will not have to spend time in creating my custom solutions and instead I would be confident and very quick in finding what I need. And as said I don't have to spend time in crawling through the entire list every-time I encounter a new problem.